# AdalServiceException: AADSTS50049: Unknown or invalid instance

Tags: c#, azure, adal

We are using ADAL 3.12 and calling `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync` to acquire the token but it's throwing the following error. If we use ADAL 2.9 with `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode` method, it works and this method is no longer available with new ADAL.

--Code:

```
public void ConfigAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            Authority = authority,
            ClientId = clientId,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUrl,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = async (context) =>
                {
                    var code = context.Code;
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("code is empty");
                    }
                    // Create a Client Credential Using an Application Key
                    ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId,
                        appKey);
                    string userObjectID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(
                        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
                    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext authContext =
                        new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext(authority,
                            new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));
                    var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?')[0]), credential);
                  //  var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", credential);

                    AuthenticationHelper.token = result.AccessToken;

                }

            }

        });
    }
```

--Error

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (BadRequest). 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (BadRequest).

Source Error: 
Line 61:                             new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext(authority,
Line 62:                                 new    NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));
Line 63:                         var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?')[0]), credential);
Line 64:                       //  var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", credential);
Line 65:                         

Stack Trace: 



[HttpRequestException:  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (BadRequest).]
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.<GetResponseAsync>d__29.MoveNext() +2842

[AdalServiceException: AADSTS50049: Unknown or invalid instance.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.  <GetResponseAsync>d__21`1.MoveNext() +3766
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)                       
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +28
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.<GetResponseAsync>d__20`1.MoveNext() +378
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92


System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +28
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.<VerifyAnotherHostByInstanceDiscoveryAsync>d__36.MoveNext() +413

[AdalException: authority_not_in_valid_list: 'authority' is not in the list of valid addresses]
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.<VerifyAnotherHostByInstanceDiscoveryAsync>d__36.MoveNext() +600
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +26
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.<FindMatchingItemAsync>d__1.MoveNext() +470
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +28
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.<UpdateFromTemplateAsync>d__44.MoveNext() +569
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +26
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.<PreRunAsync>d__61.MoveNext() +271
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +26
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.<RunAsync>d__55.MoveNext() +4495
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +28
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.<AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeCommonAsync>d__48.MoveNext() +478
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +28
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.<AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync>d__29.MoveNext() +323
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +28
DSCAzurePoC.<<ConfigAuth>b__9_0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\vivekba\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DSCAzurePoC\DSCAzurePoC\Startup.cs:63
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +26
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__1a.MoveNext() +8320
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +26
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__1a.MoveNext() +9585
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +28
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<BaseInitializeAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +810
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +26
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +427
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +26
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +287
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +26
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +937
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +26
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +287
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +26
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext() +272
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +26
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.Infrastructure.ErrorState.Rethrow() +33
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +150
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar) +42
System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +380
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: What authority are you using for your app?

Comment: authority is aadinstance plus tenant

Comment: Can you provide exact value?